# Compactness of the closed unit ball of ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$ in the topology of pointwise convergence implies that ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$ is a dual space

Tags: banach-spaces, compactness, lipschitz-functions

It is [proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388011/closed-unit-ball-is-compact) that a closed unit ball in the set of real-valued Lipschitz functions ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$ defined on a Banach space $X$ is compact for the topology of pointwise convergence.

However, I fail to understand that this implies that ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$ is a [dual space](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf). In other words, the space ${\rm Lip}_0(X)$ is a predual.

Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from a general fact that if $B$ is a Banach space and $E\subset B^*$ is a set of funtionals that separate points in $E$ and the closed unit ball of $B$ is compact with respect to the weak topology introduced by $E$, then $B$ is isometric to $({\rm span}\, E)^*$. See [this paper](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/11725/9741).

In your case $E=\{\delta_x\colon x\in X\}$.

Comment: I think it should be '$B$ is isometric to $(\overline{span(E)})^*$'.

Comment: Sure, however a normed space and its completion have the same dual space.

Comment: I am wondering why weak topology and topology of pointwise convergence of $Lip(X)$ coincide.